# error while loading shared libraries: libdr.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: libraries

I'm struggling with networking study project. I use lvns server that manages a network topology (`./lvns -t sometopology.topo`). The topology has nodes, each node should be initialized with an instance `./dr -v dr1`. 
 So I run the first command (i.e. ./lvns ...) on one shell, and try to initialize node instances, each in a separate shell. But by initializing node instances get the following error:

> error while loading shared libraries: libdr.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

So I assume I just need to install libdr.so but couldn't manage it. 
Does someone know how to fix the problem?

Comment: Where did you obtain this software? my best guess is that `libdr.so` is a locally installed library that ships with it - and may require setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in order to be found

Comment: @steeldriver Um, highly likely it's local. I have a folder with all files that are used for the project but there is no libdr.so. So, I assumed it's something that could be potentially installed.